# Checking out a remote git branch but pointing it to a different upstream

Tags: git

What's the shortest command line to check out a new branch from a remote but pointing it out to a different upstream at once?

**Suppose we have these 2 remotes:**

- `origin`: Is my own remote clone (fork) of the main project repository.
- `the-project`: Is the main project repository. We need to fetch all contributed merges from there just before we start every new task (new branch).

So, when we are about to create a new branch for a new task from `the-project/master`:

```sh
$ git fetch the-project
$ git checkout master
$ git merge
$ git checkout -B new-feature
$ git push origin new-feature -u
```

Without scripting it, is there a short way to create a new branch let's say "new-feature" from "the-project/master" but setting up the upstream to "origin/new-branch" instead? I wonder if there was something simple like: `git checkout the-project/master -B new-feature --set-upstream-to origin`

Or maybe a way to checkout a new branch unsetting the upstream like as:
`git checkout --no-auto-upstream the-project/master -B new-feature`.

Comment: In any case you can just stuff your commands into an executable script :-)

Comment: I would add `--no-track` (that's what `--no-auto-upstream` is called) to `git checkout -B` and then use `git branch --set-upstream` as a second step. Scripting is the easiest way to go, as @andreee says.

Comment: @joanis I didn't check the full checkout documentation, the "--no-track" isn't the one of the shorthand options shown by git at the short help at command line. Thanks!